# {x} = [x] - how many numbers?

Tags: real-numbers

{$x$} is like the fractional part: x - floor(x)

$[x]$ is the whole part or whatever it's called: floor(x)

Comment: Why would you say that ?

Comment: it's the first number that comes to mind and {x} is between [0,1) and if you were to take a rational number per say 0.75 [x] would be 0 and {x} would be 0.75 and they don't coincide :DD
hope my way of thinking makes sense but it's certainly wrong

Comment: No it is correct :) $\lbrace x \rbrace$ must be in $[0,1)$, and $[x]$ must be an integer, so..........

Comment: I don't understand what's the question here.

Comment: @Nikhil The question has been savagely edited, si it is now unreadable : it asked to find all the numbers $x$ such that $\lbrace x \rbrace = [x]$.

Answer (score 2):

$$x - [x] = [x]$$
$$x = 2[x]$$

Since $[x]$ is an integer, then $x$ is also an integer. But then $x=[x]$, so you have
$$x = 2x$$

to which $x=0$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're right.

$[x]$ is an integer and $\{x\}$ is in the interval $[0,1)$. The only integer in that interval is $0$.

Thus, $\{x\} = [x]$ implies $\{x\}=0$ and so $x=0$.